# SoapUI - WSHttpBinding - Windows Auth

Tags: web-services, wcf, web, automated-tests, soapui

I'm trying to call a web service which has a wshttpbinding which requires windows authentication. We have successfully been able to call the service using another tool and the config below but I'm having trouble setting up SoapUI to authenticate against the service. I keep getting the response that the message could not be processed due to invalid security. Has anyone had experience with SoapUI and been able to setup the tool to call a service which requires windows credentials, delegation and server identiy as below

```
<protocols scenario="customBinding" uiType="customBinding" xmlns="http://hp/ServiceTest/config">

  <mode>Private</mode>
  <customization>
    <textMessageEncoding />

     <security authenticationMode="SecureConversation">
      <secureConversationBootstrap authenticationMode="SspiNegotiated" />
    </security>
    <httpTransport authenticationScheme="Negotiate" />
  </customization>

  <identities>
    <server>
      <expectedUpn>***\STE1_SPM_EFI_SV</expectedUpn>
    </server>
    <client>
      <windowsCredentials allowedImpersonationLevel="Delegation">
        <username>testqa-gb</username> 
        <password>*********</password> 
        <domain>***</domain> 
    </windowsCredentials>  

    </client>    
  </identities>

</protocols>
```